# WKWebView max cached object size

Tags: ios, caching, wkwebview, capacitor

I have an Ionic capacitor react iOS application (which uses WKWebView) with local html and Rest API content

Caching is working for all the API endpoints except one which returns quite a large amount of data (2MB gzipped - 16MB un)

I'd really like this to be cached, but it seems there is a max size that WKWebView is able to store.

If I just lower the about of data the endpoint returns, then caching working i.e. I get 304s

Any ideas what the limit is, how to up the limit, or handle in some other way?

**Edit** from trial and error it appears limit is 10MB (unzipped - or some weird value of gzipped ~1.2 MB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit of WKWebView cacheable object is 10MB, stored unzipped in the cache.

It does not seem possible to legitimately up this limit (<= iOS13 at time of writing).

It is possible to intercept requests with WKWebKit, and use URLSession/URLCache directly.  Something to note is that the URLCache will only store a response IF the size of the response < ~5% of the size of the cache - and I imagine this is the same reason WKWebView doesn't cache responses >= 10MB directly.  So, in my case I have had to create a URLCache of ~600MB to accommodate this.  I tried storing the response manually with storeCachedResponse(_:for:) but seemed to get corruption when retrieving it - not looked into why, having a 600MB cache is just about acceptable for my use case.

Apple documentation states URLCache will only cache if:

- The request is for an HTTP or HTTPS URL (or your own custom
  networking protocol that supports caching).
- The request was successful (with a status code in the 200–299 range).
- The provided response came from the server, rather than out of the
  cache.
- The session configuration’s cache policy allows caching.
- The provided URLRequest object's cache policy (if applicable) allows
  caching.
- The cache-related headers in the server’s response (if present) allow
  caching.
- The response size is small enough to reasonably fit within the cache.
  (For example, if you provide a disk cache, the response must be no
  larger than about 5% of the disk cache size.)

[source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessiondatadelegate/1411612-urlsession?language=swift)

**edit** further to this I found just upping the URLCache size unreliable, and quite often got cache misses even though the Etag had not changed.  Instead I created a separate small URLCache (just over double the data I need to store). Set the cache policy to `.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` and store/retrieve the cached data manually.